# send firebase authentication token for every api call from frontend in javascript and axios

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, axios, jwt

I am building a web app that uses firebase authentication. I am trying to send the firebase token to the backend API for every call.
I could retrieve the token and print it in the console, but whenever I tried to send it to the backend, the token seems to be empty.
the backend I am using is Python django,

here is what I have tried,

token.js

```
function clienttoken(){
    
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function myuser(user) {
        if (user) {

    //window.location.href = 'index.html';
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
        var token = idToken;
        window.alert(token);
        //return token;
  })}
        });
  }
```

I was able to successfully print the token in the console.

when I tried to use this in index.html

```
<script>
      (function () {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        document.getElementById('post').onclick = function mydata () {
          var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
          
          
          var token =  clienttoken();
          
          //window.alert(token);}

            
            const config = {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer' +{token}  }
            }; 
            
          axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:7000/posts/', mydata.data,config)
            .then(function (res) {
              //output.className = 'container-fluid';
                resp = JSON.stringify(res.data.body);
                resp_new=resp.replace(/\\n/g,'\n')
              //output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res.data.body);
              $("#resp").text(resp_new);
              $("#resp").show()
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              output.className = 'container text-danger';
              output.innerHTML = err.message;
            }); 
        };
      })(); 
    </script>
```

the Axios starting to execute even before the token retrieval and an empty token is sent to the backend every time.

I tried to use the async function
token.js

```
 async function retrievetoken(){
            
            
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function mytoken(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            
            
            const idtoken =  await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
                        
                //window.alert(token);
                return idtoken;
          }
            
           else {
            // No user is signed in.
            
            window.location.href = 'login.html';
          }
        });}
```

index.html

```
 <script>
          (function () {
            var output = document.getElementById('output');
            document.getElementById('post').onclick = function mydata () {
              var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
              
              async function retrievetoken(){
              const token = await clienttoken();
              
              window.alert(token);
              }  };
          })(); 
        </script>
```

I tried to print the token, but all I get was just `[Object:Promise]`. Even after the asynchronous call, the empty token is sent to the backend.

someone, please help me with how to send the firebase token for every API call.

also please find my backend coding,

```
class GetPostList(APIView):
    cred = credentials.Certificate(r'pathto/firebase-sdk.json')

    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        
        
        jwt_token = request.META.get('Authorization')

        #jwt_token = request.headers['Authorization']

        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(jwt_token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']


        endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
        header = {"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
        send_data = request.data

        if uid is not None:  
            response = requests.post(endpoint, json=send_data, headers=header)
            return Response(response.json())
        else:

            return Response({'error': 'Token does not exist'}, status=401)
```

I think I am sure that the backend coding looks good. However, I am unable to send the token from frontend for each API call.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `token` in curly brackets? (here: const config = {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer' +{token}  }
            }; )

Answer (score 1):

When you use callback functions, the return keyword returns the callback function, not the original function. Thus, you'd want to use the `await` keyword to wait for the promise to resolve, then return that value.

To avoid this, you should use the `firebase.auth().currentUser` to get the current user, rather than creating a listener for when the user logs in or out. This also has the benefit of your function not being re-run whenever the user logs out, etc.

```js
 async function retrieveToken() {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken( /* forceRefresh */ true)
            // Because this return statement is no longer in a nested callback function, it now returns properly.
            return idtoken;
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            window.location.href = 'login.html';
        }
 }
```